# How to pass datepicker value to url.Action of image tag in MVC Controller - Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

In a form, I have image tag which are calling controller action `GetImage` (returing png image data).

It was working fine but now I introduce two datepicker fileds - fromdate and todate and I want to pass datepicker values also to controller. How can I pass these datepicker values to controller action.
This is an image tag which is working fine without passing date fields.

```
img alt="Column Chart" src="@Url.Action("GetColumnChart")
```

Could anybody helps on it?

Comment: do you want the image src to change dynamically when the user changes the date in either of the date pickers?

Comment: Yes..So there is 'Refresh' button on click of which I need to change image src.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need some fairly straightforward javascript for this. You just need to handle the click event of your "Refresh" button, get the values of the two fields and the update the image source. The cunning bit is in re-using the URL generated by MVC (so that we don't encounter routing issues). Since when the Url is generated (at page load) we don't know the final route values (from and to date), we put in a placeholder and then use some script to replace them with the values to use each time:

```
document.getElementById("RefreshButton").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  var fromdate = document.getElementById("fromdate").value;
  var todate = document.getElementById("todate").value;
  var url = '@Url.Action("GetColumnChart", new { fromdate: "FROM-PLACEHOLDER", todate: "TO-PLACEHOLDER" })'; //generate URL with placeholders
  url = url.replace("FROM-PLACEHOLDER", fromdate);
  url = url.replace("TO-PLACEHOLDER", todate);
  document.getElementById("ChartImage").src = url;
});
```

Obviously you will need to make sure all your elements have the appropriate IDs in order to access them - those I've given above are just for example. Change them to suit your code.

Comment: @PalamCoder no problem. If the answer has helped you please remember to accept the answer and/or upvote :-)